# Aframe Gizmo for Translation

Tags: three.js, aframe

I want to put a translation Gizmo on an object in aframe. I know that this can be done by calling the editor, but I would like to do this with a function rather than exposing the whole editor. I only want a gizmo on an object so its x, y, z axis can be dragged by editing.

Here is an example in three.js

http://threejs.org/examples/?q=tran#misc_controls_transform

Thanks for any advice,

Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code for it: https://github.com/aframevr/aframe-inspector/tree/master/src/lib/vendor/threejs

You'd need to wrap the TransformControls in an A-Frame component and skim through the EditorControls component to grab what you need and wrap that as well.

Comment: The link is broken.